# WordPress - manage logo to left of menu bar

Tags: wordpress

I'm a developer but I don't know wordpress well and I have just inherited a wordpress site. There's a missing logo image at the top left next to the menu bar:

[image]

I have the image file but I cannot find where that logo/image is configured inside WP. I have gone into the Menus section many times -- I find the menu items but I cannot find where that image is configured. So I need to know where/how to configure that, and also how to make the image size "fixed". By default, when the image was there (before I accidentally deleted it somehow), it stretches/expands when the user scrolls down.

My client is using the "Divi Builder" template, and this template uses some kind of custom layout/template for managing and editing the page.

The Divi theme is being used and here's what it looks like inside theme customization:
[image]

So in summary:

1. Where/how can I find that image setup so I can fix the src to point to the correct image that I have?
2. How can I prevent its default behavior of expanding while scrolling down?

Thanks!

Comment: provide code and /or fiddle

Comment: What code do you want? There's a lot, in a lot of different places.

Comment: "Divi Builder" is plugin, but there is also "Divi" theme from the same vendor. It's unclear which one you are talking about. Image size change is done through JavaScript/CSS and has nothing to do with Wordpress (although incorporating change into Wordpress theme does) - I suggest to break your question into two. Usually logo can be configured through "Theme" option in WP admin panel (or separate page, if theme registered one). Use `@username` to notify people about your comment if you address them directly.

Comment: put header code fiddle so it can be easy to understand

Comment: @MirosławZalewski It's the Divi theme and I added a screenshot in my post. btw, I'm an expert in html/css/js, but I'm lost in WP. I know how to fix the image/link, if I could just find the place where it's configured in WP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logo settings:

```
Goto dashboard->appearence->divi theme option->Generl settings.
```

other settings

```
Support Docs-> Read divi theme documention
```

Comment: In my case it was Dashboard -> Divi -> General Settings -> Logo, but you got me to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The Divi theme is a commercial theme and don't expect people on SO to have access to it. It's best to go to https://www.elegantthemes.com/forum/ for support.

> "Where/how can I find that image setup so I can fix the src to point to
>   the correct image that I have?"

The logo is uploaded and the URL set in theme options, not in the menu options.

> "How can I prevent its default behavior of expanding while scrolling
>   down?"

This is a completely separate question and is a feature of the theme. Ask theme support how to disable it. Or isolate the Javascript and other code and put it in a Fiddle so people can see how it works.

Comment: Elegant Themes charges a minimum of $69 even just to access the forums. Too much. I'll try to email them regarding both questions. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: That's what you get for using a paid theme. BTW, Divi is garbage; your content is encoded in proprietary shortcodesby Divi and the pagebuilder, and if you change themes, your content is non-transferable. Not all premium themes do that, but Divi does.